# Speeding up Excel VBA macro that searches subfolders

Tags: excel, vba, foreach

First of all, I have to say that I'm quite new to VBA. I have worked with Excel for a few years now and know it quite well, but the VBA editor is something kind of new to me.

I needed to create a macro that managed to find the parent folder where a folder with a particular name was and opened it. I managed to do so (see code below). However, the search is way too slow. The whole propose of the script is to save time and be accurate and, at the moment, looking up the folder in windows explorer is faster. The macro takes around 1-2 minutes while explorer takes 10 seconds.

I was wondering if there would be a way to speed this up.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Option Explicit
Dim FileSystem As Object
Dim S As Boolean
Dim HostFolder As String

Sub FindFolder()
HostFolder = "W:\Branches\City\Name\NAME QUOTING"
Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
S = False
DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder)
If S = False Then
    MsgBox "Folder not found"
End If
End Sub
Sub DoFolder(Folder)
    Dim SubFolder
    Dim StockCode As String
    For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
        DoFolder SubFolder
        StockCode = Selection.Value
        If SubFolder.Name Like "*" & StockCode & "*" Then
            Call Shell("explorer.exe " & SubFolder.ParentFolder, vbNormalFocus)
            S = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next SubFolder
End Sub
```

Comment: When you find your file, you need to exit the whole recursion.   Maybe change `Exit For` to `Exit Sub` and add a line after `DoFolder SubFolder`  `If S Then Exit Sub`

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindFolder()

'edited section******
dim stockcode As String
Stockcode = activecell.text
if stockcode = "" then exit sub
'end of edit 
'****************************

stockcode = "*" & stockcode & "*"  'concaternation is expensive, do only once
Dim fso As New filesystemobject
Dim topfol As Folder
Dim fol As Folder
Dim s As String
Set topfol = fso.GetFolder("W:\Branches\City\Name\NAME QUOTING") ' we start here

For Each fol In topfol.SubFolders
    If fol.Name Like stockcode Then
        s = fol.Path
        Exit For
    End If
    s = SearchFolder(fol, stockcode)
    If s <> "" Then
        Exit For
      End If


Next fol
ShowFolder s
End Sub

Sub ShowFolder(s As String)
If Len(s) > 0 Then
Shell "Explorer.exe " & s, vbNormalFocus
End If
End Sub

Public Function SearchFolder(fol As Folder, stockcode As String) As String

Dim ff As Folder
For Each ff In fol.SubFolders
    If ff.Name Like stockcode Then

        SearchFolder = ff.Path
        Exit For
    End If
    If SearchFolder(ff, stockcode) <> "" Then
     SearchFolder = ff.Path
        Exit For
    End If
 Next ff
End Function
```

Note that this version uses a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime in order to do early binding to the FileSystemObject. I'm sure this could be optimised

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, Harassed Dad, but I'm afraid I cannot run it for some reason. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong but when I hit the "run" button the macro box shows up empty.

Comment: Ahh - you're passing the stockcode as the selected cell. Hang on...
Right - see edit above

Comment: Since you specifically mentioned early binding, I'll add that indeed, early binding does provide a performance benefit, and a noticeable one in this case. The benefit tends to be negligible for one-off cases (like creating a new Outlook mail from a template) but for filesystem, and sometimes, dictionaries, it has some noticeable effect in my experience

Comment: Hello again. Thanks a lot for all the help, guys. I have tried it and, even though it let me run it, it gives me an error that says "User-defined type not definer" and it does not work. Excel highlights the following right after: Public Function SearchFolder(fol As Folder, stockcode As String) As String

Comment: Have you referenced the Microsoft Scripting Runtime? That's the most usual reason for that message. In the VB editor go to to Tools,References and make sure the runtime is ticked